# Macro code: To fetch data from CSV file to excel file

Tags: csv, xls

I want to create a macro for excel,2007. To fetch data from csv file to excel file.
Please share the code with me to run this macro.please reply :)

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried so that we can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem. Doesn't this work for you?

```
Sub Macro1()
    ChDir "C:\Users\foo\documents"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\foo\documents\test.csv"
End Sub
```